# Storing Multiple value in MutableArray with different value

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a button which on click I store the index of the current quotes into an array.
The problem is that it is overwriting the same object. How can I change it with different object of the `NSNumber` to store in the `NSMutableArray`?

```
[someButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add_favoritegold.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    NSUserDefaults *favoriteQuotes = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *ListOfIndex= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Want to change with diffrent objecy 
    **NSNumber* Wrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:index];**

    [ListOfIndex addObject:Wrapped];
    int xOut = [[ListOfIndex lastObject] intValue];
    NSLog(@"%d",xOut);
    [favoriteQuotes setObject:ListOfIndex forKey:@"Indexes"];
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, do you want to save index of selected quotes to userdefaults?

Comment: Yes ...How can i do this , Selected Quotes can me multiple and that values i am using on another view , as i am new to iphone does not know how to do this

Comment: The problem is this line: NSMutableArray *ListOfIndex= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  Which created a new array and then you added only one index... Anupdas got your solution.

Comment: Yes i already know the problem but how can i solve this that is main thing dear because i m new to iphone ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
- (void)saveFavouriteQuoteIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *savedQuoteIndexes = [[defaults objectForKey:@"Indexes"]mutableCopy];

    if (!savedQuoteIndexes) {
        savedQuoteIndexes = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    NSNumber *indexNumber = @(index);

    if (![savedQuoteIndexes containsObject:indexNumber]) {
        [savedQuoteIndexes addObject:indexNumber];

        [defaults setObject:savedQuoteIndexes forKey:@"Indexes"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }

}
```

Comment: how can i get all savedQuotesIndex one by one??

Comment: @Bhupendra Can you clarify the question you asked?

Comment: When user press the  button i want to store the index on which quotes user press and after that another view i want to display all the quotes from the saveQuotesIndex

Comment: @Bhupendra In the above method you stored index. You can see that using objectForKey: method a stored value can be retrieved. In this case it would return a NSArray. You can iterate the indexes to find the quotes from it. I hope that you have saved all the quotes and the indexes are unique identifiers for each quote.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving `ListOfIndex` with key as `Indexes`.

So, for the next whatever value, it will replace previous value having key `Indexes`.

EDIT:

Read the array

```
 NSArray *readArray=favoriteQuotes[@"Indexes"];
```

Add your new value into this same array.

Comment: Yes i know that but how can i modify so that mutable array store multiple value of NSNumber without overwriting on pervisious thank you @Anoop